# how to insert record using view having joined tables postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I've created a view from the join of two tables called students and depts; Now I want to insert a record through the view in the students table. Simple **INSERT INTO** showing error -

> ERROR:  cannot insert into view "mec_engg", DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable

Code for creating the view -

```
CREATE VIEW mec_engg AS
SELECT rollno, st_name, deptname,
AGE(current_date, bdate) AS Age
FROM students, depts
WHERE students.deptcode=depts.deptcode
AND depts.deptname='Mechanical Engineering';
```

Depts table -

```
CREATE TABLE depts(
    deptcode CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    deptname CHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Students Table -

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    rollno SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    st_name CHAR(30),
    bdate DATE CHECK(bdate>'01-JAN-97'),
    deptcode CHAR(3) REFERENCES depts(deptcode) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    hostel SMALLINT CHECK(hostel<10),
    parent_inc NUMERIC(8,1)
);
```

How can I insert the record through the view in students table?

```
INSERT INTO mec_engg(rollno, st_name, deptname, age)
VALUES (92005454, 'Abhishek Ganguly', 'Mechanical Engineering', AGE(current_date, DATE'22-Oct-2000'));
```

Comment: Ideally, one should only be **inserting in the base tables** and simply **refreshing** the view.

Comment: No, task was to insert into the base table using views. For that either **TRIGGER** or **INSTEAD OF** is important.

Comment: Yes I meant at a broader level, although It depends on the DB architecture here is a good article debating the same [link](https://hasura.io/blog/the-pros-and-cons-of-updatable-views/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a trigger instead of as mentioned in the insert command output.
Two more points are important:

1. age field does not exist in any of the students and depts tables therefore the age value cannot be in the insert command.
2. The deptcode field is a primary key and must be referenced in the insert command

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mec_engg_insert_data()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "students" ("rollno", "st_name") VALUES (NEW."rollno", 
    NEW."st_name");
    INSERT INTO "depts" (deptcode, deptname) VALUES (1, NEW."deptname");
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

    CREATE TRIGGER mec_engg_insert
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON mec_engg
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mec_engg_insert_data();

    INSERT INTO mec_engg(rollno, st_name, deptname)
    VALUES (92005454, 'Abhishek Ganguly', 'Mechanical Engineering');
   ```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me.
And thanks for marking my mistakes.

Comment: Similarly, we can do for DELETE and UPDATE right?